# Tried to follow the EC2 Juju guide and it fails

Tags: juju, amazon-ec2

I am evaluating Juju and when following the very basic tutorial https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/getting-started.html, literally following every single instruction to a T, all I end up when trying to bootstrap is this error:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx:~$ juju bootstrap
2013-04-03 22:10:48,016 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'sample'
    (origin: ppa type: ec2)...
2013-04-03 22:10:48,494 ERROR Bootstrap aborted because file storage
    is not writable: Error Message: Access Denied
```

Am I missing something? The user for which I entered the access key information has all permissions except the ability to modify IAM.

Right now, Juju is not looking so promising if I can't even get the basic tutorial to work. I started out with AMI: ubuntu/images/ebs/ubuntu-precise-12.04-amd64-server-20130325

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you running the `juju bootstrap` on your local machine or on an ec2 instance? I've done this recently, but bootstrapped on my local machine instead of the remote machine...

Answer (score 3):

The issue is the identity/account you're using doesn't have access to the s3 bucket that's configured as the control bucket. You can try changing the bucket to something unique. The s3 bucket names must be globally unique (not owned by another account). Alternatively your IAM account may not have read/write access to S3.

Answer (score 0):

As with most of those that ask the public for help for the first time, you didn't provide us with any of your config settings.

If you're using Mass, there would be one solution and by the looks of it you might be.

Further, you're also using EC2, but your default environment is 'sample'? That doesn't make sense, how come you didn't just make changes to the "amazon" environment? Maybe you forgot to change your default environment over to amazon?

If you have need for quicker answers than posting a question would allow, please refer here: http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/Installing_an_Ubuntu_Private_Cloud